# IOS Automation using UFT

Tags: ios, ui-automation, hp-uft

Can we identify the notification badge of any applcation in IOS using UFT? If so, how can it be done?

I am using UFT 12.54 and Mobile Center 2.01.

Answer (score 2):

UFT will not support as of now. due to the limitation, try with uft 14.01